# Keep getting mySQL if statement syntax error. How do i fix it?

Tags: mysql, sql

I keep getting an error. How do I run a query like this in MySQL?

`UPDATE Events SET eventName = 'hi' IF ROW_COUNT() = 0 INSERT INTO EVENTS (eventName) VALUES (`hi`);`

Basically I want to update but if there is no data to update, I insert the data. Is there a way to do it in one line?

**Edit 1**
Getting this error

```
mysql> UPDATE Events
    -> SET eventName = 'hi';

IF ROW_COUNT() = 0
THEN
    DELETE FROM Events
    WHERE EventID = 1;
END IF;
ERROR 1205 (HY000): Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction
mysql>
mysql> IF ROW_COUNT() = 0
    -> THEN
    ->     DELETE FROM Events
    ->     WHERE EventID = 1;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF ROW_COUNT() = 0
THEN
    DELETE FROM Events
    WHERE EventID = 1' at line 1
mysql> END IF;
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'END IF' at line 1
```

Comment: Explain what you are trying to do.  Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: You can't do `UPDATE` and `DELETE` in the same query. `IF` statements can only be used in stored procedures.

Comment: @GordonLinoff updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use REPLACE, so for your code:
MySQL REPLACE() replaces all the occurrences of a substring within a string.

```
REPLACE INTO Events SET eventName = 'hi'
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to use an `IF` statement you have to be in a stored procedure (or other procedural context like a trigger or scheduled event). Then it has to be two statements and you need `THEN` and `END IF`:

```
UPDATE Events
SET eventName = 'hi';

IF ROW_COUNT() = 0
THEN
    DELETE FROM Events
    WHERE EventID = 1;
END IF;
```

Comment: For some reason, I get an timeout error. I edit my post to show my error logs. Can i not run multiple sql at once?

Comment: You can't type an `IF` statement at the `mysql>` prompt. As I said in my answer, it has to be in a stored procedure.

Comment: Your first statement tries to update every row in the table. If the table is large it can take a while.